Mongodb Insert, if duplicate, return object
When using mongodb library in golang, I have a field that is unique "_id".
I want to be able to get the object in case I face a duplicate..
Is it possible in one command only instead of having to do something like:
(try to insert, if duplicate, get job)
_, err := s.coll.InsertOne(ctx, entry)
if err != nil {
    if mongo.IsDuplicateKeyError(err) {
        duplicateJob, loadErr := f.jobStore.loadPendingJob(ctx, *job.JobID)
    }
}

Thanks in advance

You can use FindOneAndUpdate with Upsert: true which will create the document if it doesn't exist. And set ReturnDocument: Before so it will return the found doc if it already exists. However, if it does exist, it will get updated. So if you want a "don't update if it exists" behaviour, you cannot use FindOneAndUpdate or even UpdateOne, since the docs will either be updated or inserted.

@aneroid I don't want it to be updated, if it exists, I just want it as it is in the collection..

Context is important. Why must it be one command and not just a simple "try to fetch and if it doesn't exist, create" pattern? Are you perhaps fearing duplicate entries through concurrency?

This can be done with an aggregation pipeline which ends with a $merge stage. However, the result of such pipeline doesn't return the existing or updated document. You would still need a second query to get that.

I think simply check by find, return or insert, is there any logical benefit of using one liner or considerable overhead of this check

As far as I can see it, you are using MongoDB as persistence layer of a (possibly distributed) job queue. Is that correct?

@MarkusWMahlberg It's not a queue it's just for storing the jobs infos that are running by another (distant) process
